# Erro ao executar hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Depois de apanhar um pouco, estou andando com meu projeto. Ao executar o projeto, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: evolutionary
    ...]
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/evolutionary]
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****, driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mai 16, 2016 6:41:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Mon May 16 18:41:22 BRT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.evolutionary.util.HibernateUtil.main(HibernateUtil.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'BRT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:620)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:68)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'BRT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:308)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2474)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1817)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1673)
    ... 35 more
```

Fala de um erro na linha 14 do código abaixo:

```
package br.com.evolutionary.util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        EntityManager em;

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("evolutionary");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();


    }

}
```

Meu arquivo persistence.xml é:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="evolutionary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/evolutionary" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Alguém sabe o motivo do erro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pelo stacktrace da exceção o motivo parecer ser o timezone, segue abaixo o trecho:

`Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'BRT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.`

Você pode forçar o uso do time zone na url de conexão, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<property key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://hostname/databaseName?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
```

Answer (score 4):

Com do Driver MySQL versão 6.0 em diante deve-se usar:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
BD_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/bd_name?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";
```

Já usei e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Após seguir o conselho do gabriel_amaral, eu obtive um novo erro onde foi mais fácil localizar o problema, então adicionei mais 2 dependências do maven e resolvi meu problema. Obrigado a todos. O link abaixo é o que me ajudou.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386771/javax-validation-validationexception-hv000183-unable-to-load-javax-el-express

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo erro e após a explicação clara, meu problema foi solucionado!

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

BD_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/bd_name?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";
```

Apenas adicionei esta linha ao meu código: `?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC`

Obrigado! ;)